# Why can't I edit my answer?

Tags: support, edits, specific-answer

[I posted an answer in 2010.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181755/why-does-footer-not-go-all-the-way-to-the-bottom/2181794#2181794)

This answer is a link-only answer. I wanted to edit it to add the essential information from the link. When I click on edit, the editing box appears but I cannot type or paste in it. I am able to edit another of my own answers.

I'm logged in and there is no pending edit.

Is it because the answer is too old?

Comment: It works for me

Comment: What browser? OS? Can you see errors in the JS console?

Comment: Unbuntu 14.04, Chrome 34.0.1847.116. I'm updating Chrome. It works well on Chrome (36) for Window7. Thank you.

Comment: As for editing: please use `\`code\`` for code, not for random formatting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no age limit in editing your posts, and I can edit your post just fine.

I've occasionally seen Chrome (35 on OS X 10.7) break the editor; the editing textbox just disappears, but the preview is still active and typing does change the text as shown in the preview area. Resizing the browser always fixes it.

As such, you should try using a different browser, or switch to the mobile view, or go to per-post edit page instead. For your old post that link is https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2181794/edit. This is linked from the [post revisions view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2181794/revisions).

Comment: I just realized that I have a old Chrome version (34).  I edited it on my laptop. Thank you!

Comment: @LucM that's why it's better to always mention what browser and what version you're using, so you can get faster help saying "probably caused by old browser".